# Output data from the database site.master MVC C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I want a variable option_name hatched in site.master.

**site.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
       <% here!!!! %>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Configs.cs**

```
[Table(Name = "Site_Config")]
public class Configs
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int ID_option { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string option_name { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string option_title { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string option_value { get; set; }
}
```

I've written in the code where I wanted to insert a variable value. I know how to do through the "Index"-view, but I would like to display a value on all pages

Answer (score 0):

You can put your option_name parameter into ViewBag object and display in on your master page. More info about using ViewBag object [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx)